# Reading a file with integers that may or may be delineated by spaces

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I have this file that is filled only with integers. I would like to, if possible, be able to read a file that may or may not have spaces delineating each integer.

Here are two visual examples.

The first one are integers that are not delineated by spaces while the second one are.

**First Example:**

```
020030090
000907000
900208005
004806500
607000208
003102900
800605007
000309000
030020050
```

**Second Example:**

```
0 3 8 0 12 0 15 16 6 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
0 11 5 0 1 0 0 14 13 0 3 9 12 7 0 0
0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 12 0 14 0 0 0 16
10 16 0 6 2 13 0 0 0 8 7 0 0 0 0 0

3 10 1 0 13 0 0 15 0 9 0 16 5 0 0 0
0 0 16 0 0 0 0 11 14 0 13 12 0 3 0 0
4 0 7 8 0 0 12 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 0
0 6 0 0 16 0 0 0 11 5 0 0 15 0 0 2

11 0 0 12 0 0 8 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 14 0
0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 11 0 0 8 16 0 9
0 0 13 0 3 6 0 7 16 0 0 0 0 11 0 0
0 0 0 2 5 0 14 0 15 0 0 4 0 13 7 1

0 0 0 0 0 14 5 0 0 0 16 2 13 0 8 10
14 0 0 0 8 0 9 0 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 0
0 0 6 15 7 1 0 3 12 0 0 13 0 2 5 0
0 0 0 0 0 15 0 12 1 14 0 3 0 6 16 0
```

**Note:**

I would also like to add that the second file might not be delineated by the same amount. This means that one integer could have one space after it and another integer could have 10 spaces after it.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried using the **split("\s+")** in combination with the **replaceAll("", " ")** but this not work in the second example because it would have more spaces and thus the split function would not work.

I have tried using **replaceAll(" ", "")** like this so that they have no spaces at all. Then I converted the string into a char array but that presented problems with integers greater than one digit(would not work with the second example as well).

**Code:**

```
public void initializeGrid(int grid[][], String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
        Scanner read = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
        int value;

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
        {     
            String line = read.nextLine();
            String [] numbers = line.trim().split("\\s+");   

            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) 
            {       
                value = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
                grid[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If the integers are not delimited, how do you know where one ends and the next begins?

Comment: @dnault I know that it is a problem, but when the user enters the path to the file, how do I know that each integer is delimited by spaces? That is why I said in the beginning if this was possible. It is much easier to not worry about this situation but I would like to deal with this situation if I can not because both files are valid.

Comment: Oh, I see. In the first case each integer is guaranteed to be in the range `[0-9]`. The second case is required for the case when the integers may be greater than 9.

Comment: @dnault Exactly, now you see my problem.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Does dnault have the correct idea? If delimited, then we assume all values between `[0-9]`; otherwise, no limits?

Comment: @AustinD Yes, but in the second example, you would not be able to tell the difference between 1 and 16 or 6 and 16 if you were to use a char array. If you were to use split and the file had more than 1 spaces, then parseInt would fail because it would try to parse an empty string.

Comment: It's no problem. Just examine your input to see which format the data is in. Then process each type differently. I'd recommend making a method `int[] parseRow(String row)` that converts the string into an array of integers. That method can call other methods depending on whether your row has spaces.

Comment: @dnault It is not easy to tell which format the data is in. In the first row, there may very well be no spaces for the first 4 integers, but after that, there may very well be spaces. My method has to be ready for those sitautions. If there is no space, then I have not choice but to use a char array because If I use readInt() or read(), it is going to read the whole line or some of it and not one by one. If the whole line had integers with spaces, then I could simply use split.

Comment: Where is the input coming from? Is this a homework assignment? I ask because if so it might be time to ask your instructor for clarification.

Comment: @dnault Nope no homework. Like I said before, I'm only trying to see if this is possible to do in a reasonable manner. If not, I could resort to telling the user to make sure that the file is delineated by spaces and save myself the trouble but to me that is a cop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommendation of @dnault in the comments above, here's an implementation that uses the Java `Collection` framework instead of a 2d `int` array. This approach has an advantage over a 2d array in that the `List` for each row contains exactly as many entries as needed. Using arrays, if a line has less than `COLUMN` values, the array will contain zeros for all remaining values.

```
public List<List<Integer>> readFile(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName));
    List<List<Integer>> values = new ArrayList<>();


    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;){
        String[] splitLine = line.trim().split("\\s+");

        if(splitLine.length < 2)
            values.add(parseSingleDigitValues(splitLine[0].toCharArray()));
        else
            values.add(parseDelimitedValues(splitLine));

    }

    return values;
}

private List<Integer> parseSingleDigitValues(char[] line) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c: line){
        values.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
    return values;

}

private List<Integer> parseDelimitedValues(String[] line) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str :line)
        values.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    return values;
}
```

The resulting `List<List<Integer>>` can then be easily converted into a 2D `int` array using the following method:

```
private int[][] asArray(List<List<Integer>> lists){
    int s1 = lists.size();
    int s2 = 0;
    for(List<Integer> sublist : lists){
        if(sublist.size() > s2)
            s2 = sublist.size();
    }

    int[][] arr = new int[s1][s2];
    for(int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++){
        List<Integer> sublist = lists.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < sublist.size(); j++){
            arr[i][j] = sublist.get(j);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**EDIT** In the end, if you clearly document your code/api then the burden is on the user to put it into proper use. I recommend you opt for simplicity in your API: Tell the user they must provide a space-delimited file. You can then provide a utility class that will convert a non-delimited file into a space-delimited file.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking in my mind. Is just I didn't want the user to enter a file with no spaces and have them see that it didn't work right but I guess telling them that it has to be delineated by spaces should suffice.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the API documentation is supposed to do---tell the user how to use the API. As long as it's clearly documented, then it's on the user to follow your guidelines.  If you decide to require space-delimiters, I recommend you throw an exception if spaces are not used or used improperly (at any point). This would help the user identify the issue as early as possible in the debugging process.